# What to do when an anonymous user insists they are the OP for an edit?

Tags: discussion, support, review, suggested-edits, user-accounts

Some edits, such as those adding information about [an OP's](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5763/what-is-the-meaning-of-op) system, should only be made...

- by the OP, *or*
- at the OP's explicit request, *or*
- by someone who is merely putting the information into the question, from what the OP has actually said (usually from comments).

It's not, generally speaking, safe to assume that anonymous edits are faithful to this. Wrong edits, adding "me too" information, are pretty common. Such edits should generally be rejected since information from someone else's system may not be true of the OP's system.

But I doubt it's common for someone to *maliciously* edit a post to add incorrect system information. Given that, **what should I do when someone claiming to be the OP suggests an edit as an anonymous user**?

That situation currently pertains to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157173/cant-load-windows-without-plugging-in-the-external-drive), but I'm also interested in knowing how to respond to this in general. (I don't plan to post a new meta question *every* time this happens.)

Should I:

- ...accept the edit?
- ...reject it?
- ...flag the post for moderator attention so that the user can be helped to log in, or heuristic factors (like if the anonymous user's IP is the same) can be assessed?
- Something else?

> <sub>**This question has since been asked on other [child metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298735/what-is-child-meta-in-stackexchange),
>   too:**</sub>
>
> - [What do I do when a user edits their question with another account](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4621/what-do-i-do-when-a-user-edits-their-question-with-another-account) (on [Unix & Linux Meta](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/))
> - [Should I perform a duck test when reviewing suggested edits?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12690/should-i-perform-a-duck-test-when-reviewing-suggested-edits) (on [Super User Meta](https://meta.superuser.com/))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I approve if they aren't obviously a vandal. We can't do a IP check, or anything like that so its a little difficult, but again, if it isn't vandalizing (and adds value to the question) then by all means, approve it.

Comment: It can always be rolledback later.

Comment: Supplementary Comment: If the user does not have 2k reputation, all their edits need reviewing.  My advice is to review the changes themselves, and not focus on a user saying "oh, I'm the original poster.", but rather focus on the content of the edits being done.

Comment: @LordofTime very true.